# using ui-sref within directive and using the directive in different modules

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have *app* and *admin* modules responsible for *example.com/* and *example.com/admin* respectively. 
In each of them I use the same `<user-list>` directive. there is a link to user profile inside `<user-list>` directive. 
so when accessed from *localhost/admin/users*, I want the link to be *example.com/admin/user/id* 
and when accessed from localhost, I want the link to be example.com/user/id

admin.html: `<user-list from="admin"></user-list>`
directive.html: `<md-button ui-sref="{{from}}.user.profile({user.id})">profile</md-button>`

config: `$stateProvider.state('admin.user.profile', {
        url: '/details/:id',
        ....`

this is not working. the link is not generated. no error or something. how I can I achieve this?

Comment: `{{from}}.user.profile({id: user.id})` is correspending to your state and yeilds `admin.user.profile({id: user.id})`

Comment: you are right. It works. I just put the corresponding state. Somehow I was expecting ui-sref to compile a link even if it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code there. The problem was that I didn't have the corresponding state and somehow expected to see a link even when it was a wrong link.